# Point Similarity Clustering

Tags: clustering, autocorrelation, spatial-cluster

I am new to geographical statistics so please pardon this question if it is a duplicate. I would like to test if points that are similar are more or less likely to be near each other. I am latitude and longitude data for several alligator nests. I need to know if a singly sired nest is more likely to be near another singly sired nest or not. What would be the most appropriate way to formally test this?

Comment: "*if a singly sired nest is more likely to be near another singly sired nest or not*". Are you interested only in whether the nearest neighbor is also singly sired...or in the median/mean distance from singly sired nests to different nest types (perhaps with some maximum search radius)...and is this all with straight line distance or with corridor distance?

Comment: I'm only interested in whether the nearest neighbor is also singly sired right now and this would be with straight line distance.

Comment: Try the R code from this post, it will return Ripley's-K (Besag's-L) statistic, showing spatial relationships at various distance lags. Even though the question appears to be quite different, the presented answer will most certainly address your problem. However, I would note that you really should transform your data into a distance-based projected system. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/determining-if-trees-within-forest-gaps-are-clustered-using-r/42485#42485

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining if trees within forest gaps are clustered using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/determining-if-trees-within-forest-gaps-are-clustered-using-r)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading over ESRI's documentation on [Patterns](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-analyzing-patterns-toolset.htm), [Clusters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-mapping-clusters-toolset.htm), and [Spatial Relationships](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-modeling-spatial-relationships-toolset.htm). Even if you don't have access to ArcGIS, this is a clear, concise, and surprisingly thorough account of the available analyses.

The solution will depend on the specific structure of your data and your specific desired outcome.